# Trace arc from two points and center in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, geometry

I am trying to clean this figure that I've produced with python and matplotlib - I would like for each pair of red points on the same cicle be connected by an arc (or partial circle). However, I have only managed to plot the entirety of the circles.

The end goal is to get a clean offset of my convex shape (black outline), in a continuous dashed red line.

[image: Convex Hull and its Offset]

I know the coordinates of the center of each circle, and the coordinates of each red dot. Does anyone know how I could go about this? Also, each circle has the same diameter.

Comment: geometry hint: you can easily find `min_x`, `max_x`, `min_y`, `max_y` to get a rectangular boundary box. next you can "cut" its corners by the lines connecting points on the boundary box. you should do it in a while loop, until all other points are inside the boundary. take a look at [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Arc.html with the same `width` and `height`.